# Reduce pointwise function addition Stacksize

Tags: r, functional-programming, purrr

I have to pointwise add some functions (for homework), I could do this manually, but as a big fan of functional programming I want to score some style-points. Stacksize and max recursion depths spoil the fun.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to implement this more efficiently? (Or did I make a mistake somewhere else?)

```
require(purrr)

A <- function(x) x+2
B <- function(y) y^2
C <- function(z) z*3

add_funs <- function(...){
  reduce(list(...), function(a,b){
    function(x){
      a(x)+b(x)
    }
  })
}

test <- add_funs(A,B,C)
test(2)

# Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
# Error during wrapup: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?

test2 <- add_funs(A,B)
test2(2)

# Error: C stack usage  7969380 is too close to the limit
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution, that does only create a stack with one level of function evaluations, I should really get to do the actual work now.

```
add_funs_2 <- function(...){
  function(x){
    reduce(map(list(...), function(a){a(x)}), `+`)
  }
}

test3 <- add_funs_2(A,B,C)
test3(2)
# 14
```